# Android Roboguice ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: android, robolectric

What does the following crash indicate and is there a way other than removing Roboguice or upgrading the version to prevent this crash?

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>          at com.google.inject.internal.MoreTypes.canonicalize(SourceFile:128)
>          at com.google.inject.TypeLiteral.(SourceFile:89)
>          at com.google.inject.TypeLiteral.get(SourceFile:157)
>          at com.google.inject.Key.(SourceFile:132)
>          at com.google.inject.Key.get(SourceFile:243)
>          at roboguice.inject.ContextScope.enter(SourceFile:87)
>          at roboguice.inject.ContextScope.(SourceFile:61)
>          at roboguice.RoboGuice.newDefaultRoboModule(SourceFile:209)
>          at roboguice.RoboGuice.extractModulesFromManifest(SourceFile:162)
>          at roboguice.RoboGuice.getOrCreateBaseApplicationInjector(SourceFile:150)
>          at roboguice.RoboGuice.getOrCreateBaseApplicationInjector(SourceFile:90)
>          at roboguice.RoboGuice.getInjector(SourceFile:197)
>          at roboguice.activity.RoboFragmentActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:60)
>          at com.myapp.ui.activities.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:61)
>          at com.myapp.ui.activities.LauncherActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:27)
>          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5975)
>          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2378)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5255)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652) Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: type
>          at org.roboguice.shaded.goole.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(SourceFile:229)
>          at com.google.inject.TypeLiteral.(SourceFile:89)
>          at com.google.inject.TypeLiteral.get(SourceFile:164)
>          at com.google.inject.internal.MoreTypes.(SourceFile:56)
>          at com.google.inject.internal.MoreTypes.canonicalize(SourceFile:128)
>          at com.google.inject.TypeLiteral.(SourceFile:89)
>          at com.google.inject.TypeLiteral.get(SourceFile:157)
>          at com.google.inject.Key.(SourceFile:132)
>          at com.google.inject.Key.get(SourceFile:243)
>          at roboguice.inject.ContextScope.enter(SourceFile:87)
>          at roboguice.inject.ContextScope.(SourceFile:61)
>          at roboguice.RoboGuice.newDefaultRoboModule(SourceFile:209)
>          at roboguice.RoboGuice.extractModulesFromManifest(SourceFile:162)
>          at roboguice.RoboGuice.getOrCreateBaseApplicationInjector(SourceFile:150)
>          at roboguice.RoboGuice.getOrCreateBaseApplicationInjector(SourceFile:90)
>          at roboguice.RoboGuice.getInjector(SourceFile:197)
>          at roboguice.activity.RoboFragmentActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:60)
>          at com.myapp.ui.activities.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:61)
>          at com.myapp.ui.activities.LauncherActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:27)
>          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5975)
>          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2378)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5255)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)

Comment: Just to give at least something to this post I'm writing my comment. Sorry for that! The comment - I remember some conversations before and all of them end up that they are not compatible. I would ask on Roboguice github page